# Отправка сообщений из php в ajax

Tags: javascript, php

Сразу извиняюсь за тему дубликат, но там я так и не смог найти решение проблемы.
В кратце: на страница форма регистрации, пользователь жмет на кнопку и данные отправляются в php, скрипт пхп записывает данные в БД и отправляет письмо с активацией на почту юзеру, также прописаны проверки и оповещения, оповещения отправляются в формате json на ajax, но у аякса всегда срабатывает событие error, а не success, но при этом пхп скрипт отрабатывает корректно и отправляет письмо на почту. Выяснил что виновником являлась библиотека phpMailer, которая служит для отправки сообщений юзерам. Без неё события success отрабатывает. Попрорборвал использовать стандартную php функцию mail(), но с ней та же история. Как решить проблему?
**Javascript**:

```
('.login__form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Registration.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            login: login,
            password: pass1,
            email: email,
            referral: referral
        },
        success: function(res) {

            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.message);
            console.log(res.color);
            if (res.color=='green'){
                        Notification(res.message);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.alert').css('background',res.color);
                        Notification(res.message);
                        return false
                    }
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage,res) {
            console.log($.parseJSON(res));
              $('.alert').css('background','red');
              Notification('Error!');
                console.log("Error: ", errorMessage);

        }

    });
});
```

**PHP**:

```
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
       if ($success) {
           $message = 'Message send! Check your E-mail for confirm registration!';
                    $color = 'green';
                    $out = array(
                        'message' => $message,
                        'color' => $color
                    );

                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($out);

}
```

**Ошибка**

```
Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (VM27 jquery.min.js:4)
    at zb (VM27 jquery.min.js:4)
    at z (VM27 jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM27 jquery.min.js:4)
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Запустил у себя. Ответ `success`.  Проблема не в `mail`. Чтобы разобраться подробнее - 1. Выведите передаваемые данные `data`, что увидеть какие данные передаются. 2. В файле `php` покажите данные `$to, $subject, $message, $headers`.

Comment: откройте в браузере консоль разработчика, вкладку сеть и смотрите что приходит в ответ от сервера. помимо json там небось пара варнингов или нотисов по поводу работы кода, а затем что заголовки не могут быть отправлены, а потом уже ваш json, Либо после json вывод еще чего-либо.

Comment: @Denis640Kb сейчас сделаю, но когда я тестил просто добавление записей в БД, без отправки почты, то success срабатывал и оповещения приходили

Comment: @Ayurpwnz После запуска Вашего кода (Были заменены лишь те параметры, которые я указал выше) мне вернулось сообщение `success`. В тоже время и сообщение было успешно отправлено на почту и получено. Вероятней всего, как написал teran, у Вас появляется ошибка при отправке почты. Чтобы выяснить причину ошибки, надо либо вывести все ошибки в данном файле `php` и попытаться его запустить отдельно, либо проверить передаваемые данные, чтобы так же выявить причину возможной ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Если все так корректно и безошибочно, после `application/json`, можете сами отдать код 200, тогда придет в событие `success` однозначно.

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-response-code.php